# how to generate dynamic hyperlink in Jsp using Struts2 without using iterator

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I need to write a JSP to display list of users in hyperlink, retrieved from DB.
and on clicking hyperlink, I should display the name of the user in next page.

There is restriction to it, No javascript should be used.

Comment: can you make your question bit clearer please

Comment: The struts2 iterator does not use javascript from your question it sounds like the two are somehow related.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. You can make use of `Scriptlets`. You will be looping around your list, anyway
2. Creating an `HTML` string in the servlet, and spit that out to the response writer. You might need to loop your list (means using iterator in a sense)
3. In case you need to avoid loop, try recursion.

But `<s:iterator>` is a better way if you are using Struts2 and there is no JavaScript involve, whatsoever. For example,

```
<s:iterator>
 ....
</s:iterator>
```

BTW, why you don't want to use `iterator-tag`? if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari : please alter above answer as comment for the above question

Comment: AFAICS, my this post is containing an answer, so it is actually an answer. Now (after editing) it should be fine, I believe.

Comment: i think she may contain user details in arraylist and as she want to display users with hyperlink in dashboard manner, so she need to iterate the the arraylist. So iterator will be used there.

Comment: @Damodar: She stated in the headline that "without using iterator".

Comment: but in question she said as no javascript used

Comment: @Damodar: Therefore, I took care of both in my answer. :)